# I can't modify a collection of forms when I edit an entity

Tags: forms, symfony, collections

I've been following the cookbook for embed a collection of forms inside other form. I have the two entities with a relation and the two forms for each one.

Moreover, I have create the adder method: This is the code for the constructor and the adder method:

```
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->budgetDetails = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add budgetDetails
 *
 * @param \Dentoleti\BudgetBundle\Entity\BudgetDetail $budgetDetails
 *
 * @return Budget
 */
public function addBudgetDetail(\Dentoleti\BudgetBundle\Entity\BudgetDetail $budgetDetails)
{
    $budgetDetails->setBudget($this);

    $this->budgetDetails->add($budgetDetails);

    return $this;
}
```

Also, I have added the JQuery explained in the [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) and everything seems to be ok. I have created one entity and several items for the collection. The main entity and the entities of the collection have been persisted and well related.

The problem is when I try to modify this element after that. I can recover the main entity and the collection but I can't add a new element on this collection. I add a new one item and the form is show, I can fill the content of the collection but the element is not persisted on database.

It seems that the adder method is not invoked. I have used a var_dump inside the adder and it's not showing the message. Any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Did you specify allow_add option to be true on the collection form type?

Comment: Yes I did and also, the 'by_reference' param is set to false.

Comment: I think your addBudgetDetail method should do this: `$this->budgetDetails[] = $budgetDetail;` However, seems to me that you get collection of collections, instead of collection of budgetDetails.

Comment: I have tried this and it's not the solution. What I have contrasted is the fact that the getBudgetDetail() method is being called instead the adder but I don't know why.